# Windows Server R2 Task Scheduler - Open Programs On Startup

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, task-scheduler

I want Fiddler and some other programs to run on startup, so it's there and running every time I bring up an instance of my test server on EC2. There's a few questions about running scripts on Startup with Task Scheduler, but this needs to work slightly differently.

I have set this up to run on startup but when I RDP into the server I can see Fiddler is running in Task Manager (so I can't manually run a second instance of the program), but it's not viewable on the task bar? So I can't actually see the interface?

Here's my setup:

General Tab

- Running with highest privileges
- Run whether user is logged on or not
- Configure for Windows 2008 server R2

Triggers Tab

- At startup

Others are obvious and defaults..

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This guide shows you exactly how to do it with a utility called 'Always Up'

[How to Run Fiddler as a Windows Service with AlwaysUp](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/RunFiddlerAsAService.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be executing this at the wrong time.  At startup the system will start the programs as you have seen but they are not running under a user context, just the system context.

If you are expecting to use these programs as a user you will want to create a task to start the programs on login and not startup.

A user context does not exist at startup to run the programs with, therefore you cannot take ownership or use those programs when you login.

Comment: I see what you are saying, so you think it cannot be done? I am using Amazon EC2, when I start up an instance I want Fiddler to be started at startup.. When I login I want to see what Fiddler has captured..